# Connect from excel to oracle using oracle instant client

Tags: oracle, excel, connection

What are the steps to be taken to use oracle instant client to connect from excel to oracle database.  I have the unzipped basic instant client folder. The OS used is Windows XP.

Here is my connection string:

```
strConnection = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=servername;
                Uid=username;Pwd=password;"
```

I have done the following :

1. Set environment path for ORACLE_HOME, PATH and TNS_ADMIN
2. In HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE I have create a key with name Oracle with String name ORACLE_HOME and set the variable..

But when I try to connect from Excel I am getting error as oracle client and networking not found.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [ODBC supplement](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/oci/instantclient/releasenotes/ODBC_IC_ReleaseNotes.html)?